# How i can export RAS (Real Application Security) objects from ORACLE DB

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-ras

I use RASADM-tool to create RAS objects interactively. But now i need to deploy RAS objects from DEV to TEST. Are there any tools to export this objects (SQL Developer addons or similar) ?

Answer (score 3):

I was tired of waiting and has writing free open-source export application available on GitHub

https://github.com/glebovpavel/RAS-Export

Answer (score 0):

Use PL/SQL procedure (DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL).